# Reading rows from Hive table and write to file in Scala-Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I want to read  data rows  from one of the hive table in spark-scala  program.After this , same data  needs to write into a file row by row . 
Actually write to file row by row.
Could  anyone  share pointers? Spark version 1.6,Hive1.2.

Answer (score 0):

You can read from the table like so...

```
val mydf = hiveContext.sql("select * from hive_table_name")

mydf.write.save.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header", "true").save(hdfs_path_to_save)
```

here is help with the csv parser that you need if it's before Spark 2.0 
https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv

Comment: Thank you Mike. But  in my case  I have read data rows from hive tables instead of  csv file. Not output also need in some txt format not in csv.